# Basic program for calculating money

Tags: c++

I have a basic assignment and can't get the program right. The assignment is to make a program that displays the minimum amount of banknotes and coins necessary to pay.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int pari;
    cin >> pari;
    switch (pari)
    {
        case 1: cout << pari/5000 << "*5000" << endl;
        break;
        case 2: cout << pari/1000 << "*1000" << endl;
        break;
        case 3: cout << pari/500 << "*500" << endl;
        break;
        case 4: cout << pari/100 << "*100" << endl;
        break;
        case 5: cout << pari/50 << "*50" << endl;
        break;
        case 6: cout << pari/10 << "*10" << endl;
        break;
        case 7: cout << pari/5 << "*5" << endl;
        break;
        case 8: cout << pari/2 << "*2" << endl;
        break;
        case 9: cout << pari/1 << "*1" << endl;
        break;
        default: cout << "WRONG";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For example:

Input:

```
54321
```

Output:

```
10x5000
4x1000
0x500
3x100
0x50
2x10
0x5
0x2
1x1
```

I tried with `switch` case, with `if` statements, but nothing works.

Comment: You need to loop over the banknotes from biggest to smallest. Inside that loop, you need to check if the *remaining amount* is still bigger than the banknotes, if so, increase the count for this banknote and reduce your money amount by the same. Once your money amount is to small for the banknote, continue with the next smaller banknote.

Comment: Sorry to say so. Your code is completely wrong. You should first learn to use the basic language concepts. There are plenty of books and tutorials.

Comment: @treuss -- I may be wrong, but I think the problem is more involved than that.  A greedy algorithm approach may not produce the minimum number of banknotes.  Granted, your explanation is where the OP should start from.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie -- You are correct for the general problem, however for the banknotes mentioned the greedy algorithm should work just fine.

Comment: Does anybody know if there is a currency in the world, where a greedy algorithm does not work? Probably an interesting question.

Comment: Greed and currency *do* have a habit of flocking together.

Answer (score 2):

To get the kind of output you have shown, use logic that looks more like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int pari;
    cin >> pari;

    cout << pari/5000 << "*5000" << endl;
    pari %= 5000;

    cout << pari/1000 << "*1000" << endl;
    pari %= 1000;

    cout << pari/500 << "*500" << endl;
    pari %= 500;

    cout << pari/100 << "*100" << endl;
    pari %= 100;

    cout << pari/50 << "*50" << endl;
    pari %= 50;

    cout << pari/10 << "*10" << endl;
    pari %= 10;

    cout << pari/5 << "*5" << endl;
    pari %= 5;

    cout << pari/2 << "*2" << endl;
    pari %= 2;

    cout << pari/1 << "*1" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/dmzA7Q)

Which can be simplified if you put the banknotes in an array and loop through it, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int bankNotes[] = {5000, 1000, 500, 100, 50, 10, 5, 2, 1};
    const int numBankNotes = sizeof(bankNotes)/sizeof(bankNotes[0]);

    int pari;
    cin >> pari;

    for (int i = 0; i < numBankNotes; ++i) {
        cout << pari/bankNotes[i] << "*" << bankNotes[i] << endl;
        pari %= bankNotes[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/8bHDn0)

Answer (score 0):

I have written several versions for you here.
Hopefully it will help you to understand the procedure.

- Version 1

This is a navie version. This is how we would do it if we were doing it by hand.

```cpp
int main()
{
  int input_value = 0;
  std::cin >> input_value;         // First we get the input.
                                   // We start with the highest value banknote.

  int       value                = input_value;
  int const number_of_5000_notes = value / 5000; // How many of these notes do 
                                                 // we need?
  value                          = value % 5000; // Now calculate the rest.

  int const number_of_1000_notes = value / 1000; // How many of these notes do 
                                                 // we need? 
  value                          = value % 1000; // Now calculate the rest.
  int const number_of_500_notes  = value / 500;
  value                          = value % 500;
  int const number_of_100_notes  = value / 100;
  value                          = value % 100;
  int const number_of_50_notes   = value / 50;
  value                          = value % 50;
  int const number_of_10_notes   = value / 10;
  value                          = value % 10;
  int const number_of_5_notes    = value / 5;
  value                          = value % 5;
  int const number_of_2_notes    = value / 2;
  value                          = value % 2;
  int const number_of_1_notes    = value;

  // At the end we write the output           
  std::cout << "Input: " << input_value << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Output:" << std::endl;
  std::cout << number_of_5000_notes << " x 5000" << std::endl;
  std::cout << number_of_1000_notes << " x 1000" << std::endl;
  std::cout << number_of_500_notes << " x 500" << std::endl;
  std::cout << number_of_100_notes << " x 100" << std::endl;
  std::cout << number_of_50_notes << " x 50" << std::endl;
  std::cout << number_of_10_notes << " x 10" << std::endl;
  std::cout << number_of_5_notes << " x 5" << std::endl;
  std::cout << number_of_2_notes << " x 2" << std::endl;
  std::cout << number_of_1_notes << " x 1" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

- Version 2

This is a more advanced version

```cpp
int main()
{
  int value = 0;
  std::cin >> value; // Get input

  // Check input
  if (value == 0)
  {
    std::cout << "No value or 0 has been entered";
    return 0;
  }

  // Output on the fly
  std::cout << "Input: " << value << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Output:" << std::endl;

  // loop over a sorted list of banknotes.
  for (auto note_value_ent : {5000, 1000, 500, 100, 50, 10, 5, 2, 1})
  {
    int const number_of_notes = value / note_value_ent;
    value %= note_value_ent;
    std::cout << number_of_notes << " x " << note_value_ent << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Both versions give the same result (except in the case of an invalid entry).